# how to compare 2 phone numbers PHP

Tags: php, compare, phone-number

I have several ways to write a phone number :

```
+5511999999999
55999999999
11999999999
999999999
```

is there any library or logic way to compare phone numbers in PHP?

Comment: You could write some [regex](http://www.php.net/preg_match).

Comment: You could take the length of the smallest string. Then check if the right most part (of that length) of the next longest string matches. Then you could declare that these two are same phone numbers. You would need to check in a phone library for the remaining parts (many are available - in country code lists including state & country phone codes).

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question.

In order to compare two strings (as phone number or email for example) you have to be sure to have them written in similar format.

I suggest to perform validation of the entry of your forms when you get the phone numbers from the user. This way will allow you to compare strings that have the same template. for example: Country code: [+XXX] Area Code: [(XXX)] Phone Number: [XXX-XXXX] 
The user should write something like +44(887)345-5532 (for UK PHONE).

If you have file or list with some phones that you would like to compare, you have to come up with a criteria for Country code, area code and actual phone number in order to compare them with no mistakes.

When this is done you can split the string and compare each element.

There are many open source methods of doing such validation. Try and use ZEND FRAMEWORK, or CAKE PHP, CODE IGNITER or some similar framework and see how to do it there.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting approach to the problem could be considering a percentage of similarity. For this case you could use `similar_text`. I built a function thtat takes an array of phone numbers and compares them to one number like this:

```
function similarPhone($search, $phones, $acceptablePercentage)
{
    foreach ($phones as $phone) {
        similar_text($search, $phone, $percentage);
        if ($percentage >= $acceptablePercentage) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

So I use an acceptable percentage of 80% to compare.